# mysql !php login script! xampp, localhost phpmyadmin where do i start

Tags: mysql, authentication, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make a login script.
I downloaded mysql, xampp, wamp.
Already had filezilla.
I started off messing around in xampp control panel
trying to figure out how to make a database so i can make a table for username, password.
I installed phpmyadmin finally got it to accept my host, user, pass
then i realize i see this error in localhost/phpmyadmin

Error

SQL query: DocumentationEdit Edit

SELECT `tables`
FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_recent`
WHERE `username` = 'root'

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1142 - SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'pma_recent'

I'm really frustrated.
I want to uninstall everything and restart but i don't know exactly what to download.
After i uninstall everything should i just download xampp as i hear it comes with mysql, phpmyadmin or what?

I think im having trouble because i can only find outdated tutorials on how to make login scripts, and also everybody uses different webservers or w/e.

I also need help understanding this code...
should i leave localhost as it is?
                             ??        user   pass
$conect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123")

mysql_select_db"whatsmydb?"

Would i replace whatsmydb? with users?

This is what i see under databases
information_schema  Check Privileges Check Privileges
    mysql   Check Privileges Check Privileges
    performance_schema  Check Privileges Check Privileges
    sakila  Check Privileges Check Privileges
    test    Check Privileges Check Privileges
    users   Check Privileges Check Privileges
    world   Check Privileges Check Privileges
    Total: 7

The more and more i try the more and more i get confused LOL
Can someone please help me create a login script and
what should i use to create it?
Does anyone have a new tutorial for mysql5.5?
Why am i getting this error?
How do i setup a table containing usernames passwords?
I am toooo confused where shall i start?!?!?!!?!?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not included the PHP tag for this and it sounds like you're trying to use PHP connection code to access a MySQL database.  You need to first understand a couple concepts with your server environment.

1. Your Server is the computer running the software
2. Your Database Server is MySQL (software running on the computer)
3. Your Host is the IP address or HOSTNAME of the computer (i.e. localhost or 127.0.0.1)
4. Your Database Name is the name of the database you create (I'll get to that)
5. PhpMyAdmin is a web-based application that allows you to manipulate your MySQL database

**Okay let's start with PhpMyAdmin and creating your first database:**

If you click the "house" icon on the left you will be on the home screen and you will see a form field in the main content area you can type in a database name and "Create New Database" then click "Create".  Type in **myfirstdb** if that is the name of the database and click "Create"

This will refresh the column to the left and there is a drop-down (combo) menu that displays the database names (like the ones you mentioned).  You should now see **myfirstdb** listed there too.  Select it.

Now you will see very little content but in the right main content area at the bottom is a form field that allows you to create a table name and determine how many fields it has.  Type in **users** and select **4** as the number of fields.  Then click "Go" to the far right.

A form displays 4 rows and you must name your fields (columns) and I suggest you name the following and choose the following data types:

- id     INT      AUTO_INCREMENT
- name   VARCHAR(48)
- username  VARCHAR(24)
- password  VARCHAR(24)
- be sure to check the small key icon next to the **id** field to declare it as primary key.  Then click "Go" to create your table **users**.

Congratulations, you've created your first table.  Now if you're feeling brave, you could skip these steps and click the "SQL" tab in PhpMyAdmin and paste the following SQL code and it will create the table as well:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(48), username VARCHAR(24), password VARCHAR(24), PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

---

The code you were trying in your question is PHP code to connect to a database.  Here is an example of a proper connection assuming you followed the instructions above:

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("myfirstdb") or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve all the data from the "example" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users")
or die(mysql_error());  

// store the record of the "example" table into $row
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

// Print out the contents of the entry     
echo "Name: ".$row['name'];
echo "User: ".$row['username'];
echo "Pass: ".$row['password'];

?>
```

---

Note that we have not stored any data into your table, so you can click the "Insert" tab in PhpMyAdmin for that selected **users** table and insert rows, or you can insert them using SQL.  Example SQL to insert a couple users (click the SQL tab and paste this):

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, "My Buddy", "user1", "password1"), (2, "My Enemy", "badguy1", "password2");
```

---

From here you really need to read some tutorials online step-by-step to create an application.  Your login script will require HTML programming for your form, then PHP programming to receive the form submission, then PHP + SQL programming to check the user against the database.  Search for an example and use these basics to create what you need.

---

** added bonus for your generous rating **

Check this out: 
 - http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-login-form.html
 - http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html  (might be better)

Comment: Much thanks mike. I guess i will re-install everything and try this unless you know how to fix this under in phpmyadmin on the left side i see: "SQL query: DocumentationEdit Edit

SELECT `tables`
FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_recent`
WHERE `username` = 'root'

MySQL said: Documentation
#1142 - SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'pma_recent'
"
under sql tab i see:
" SELECT `tables` FROM `phpmyadmin`.`pma_recent` WHERE `username` = 'root'"

should i just delete this to fix?

Comment: first open your config file and follow these instructions:  http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Quick_Install   you have no user declared in your configs if you see that ''  so you need a valid user first to log into the database.

Comment: also, check out the additional link I added at bottom of my answer.  That should prove helpful for you.  Good luck with your project and welcome to the "addiction" (coding) ;-)

Comment: Thanks alot! I wish you best of luck with whatever you are doing also!

Answer (score 1):

Open up `config.inc.php` in your PHPMyAdmin root folder and comment out the following line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
```

This disables the "Advanced phpMyAdmin features" – whatever they are – and lets the normal features work properly.

Answer (score 1):

create pma user and apply the privilege to the phpadmin table

Instead of using the creat_tables.sql

SQL Commands to set up the pmadb as described in the documentation.

- This file is meant for use with MySQL 5 and above!
- This script expects the user pma to already be existing. If we would put a
- line here to create him too many users might just use this script and end
- up with having the same password for the controluser.
- This user "pma" must be defined in config.inc.php (controluser/controlpass)
- Please don't forget to set up the tablenames in config.inc.php

Database : `phpmyadmin`

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `phpmyadmin`
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
USE phpmyadmin;
```

Privileges

```
 (activate this statement if necessary)
 GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ON `phpmyadmin`.* TO
    'pma'@localhost;
```

Table structure for table `pma_bookmark`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_bookmark` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `dbase` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `user` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `label` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `query` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
  COMMENT='Bookmarks'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Table structure for table `pma__column_info`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_column_info` (
  `id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `column_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `comment` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `mimetype` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `transformation` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `transformation_options` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `db_name` (`db_name`,`table_name`,`column_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Column information for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Table structure for table `pma__history`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_history` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `timevalue` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `sqlquery` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `username` (`username`,`db`,`table`,`timevalue`)
```

)
  COMMENT='SQL history for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

Table structure for table `pma__pdf_pages`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_pdf_pages` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `page_nr` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `page_descr` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`page_nr`),
  KEY `db_name` (`db_name`)
)
  COMMENT='PDF relation pages for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Table structure for table `pma__recent`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_recent` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tables` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`)
)
  COMMENT='Recently accessed tables'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Table structure for table `pma__table_uiprefs`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_table_uiprefs` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `prefs` text NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`db_name`,`table_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Tables'' UI preferences'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Table structure for table `pma__relation`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_relation` (
  `master_db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `master_table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `master_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `foreign_db` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `foreign_table` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `foreign_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`master_db`,`master_table`,`master_field`),
  KEY `foreign_field` (`foreign_db`,`foreign_table`)
)
  COMMENT='Relation table'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Table structure for table `pma__table_coords`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_table_coords` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `pdf_page_number` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `x` float unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `y` float unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`,`pdf_page_number`)
)
  COMMENT='Table coordinates for phpMyAdmin PDF output'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Table structure for table `pma__table_info`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_table_info` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `display_field` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Table information for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Table structure for table `pma__designer_coords`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_designer_coords` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `x` INT,
  `y` INT,
  `v` TINYINT,
  `h` TINYINT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`db_name`,`table_name`)
)
  COMMENT='Table coordinates for Designer'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Table structure for table `pma__tracking`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_tracking` (
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `schema_snapshot` text NOT NULL,
  `schema_sql` text,
  `data_sql` longtext,
  `tracking` set('UPDATE','REPLACE','INSERT','DELETE','TRUNCATE','CREATE DATABASE','ALTER DATABASE','DROP DATABASE','CREATE TABLE','ALTER TABLE','RENAME TABLE','DROP TABLE','CREATE INDEX','DROP INDEX','CREATE VIEW','ALTER VIEW','DROP VIEW') default NULL,
  `tracking_active` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`db_name`,`table_name`,`version`)
)
  COMMENT='Database changes tracking for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Table structure for table `pma__userconfig`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_userconfig` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `timevalue` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `config_data` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`username`)
)
  COMMENT='User preferences storage for phpMyAdmin'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

the problem was with the extra _

Comment: Did you copy this from here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486434/can-i-download-the-phpmyadmin-database